# Append array_merge if it meets conditional

Tags: php

So I wanted to get some input from the community and see how I would be able to do this and if I'm just overthinking it.

**So I have this small snippet**:

```
if (get_field('featured_posts')) {
    $acf_post_ids = get_field('featured_posts', false, false);
    $acf_query = get_posts([
        'post_type' => ['any'],
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'post__in' => $acf_post_ids,
        'orderby' => 'post__in',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ]);
    $args['post__not_in'] = $acf_post_ids;
}
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
$main_ids = array_unique(array_merge($acf_query, $wp_query->posts));
```

What would be the proper way to do this:

1. If there is no `get_field('featured_posts')` set the `$main_ids` variable as just `$wp_query->posts`
2. Otherwise if there is `get_field('featured_posts')` set `$main_ids` to `array_unique(array_merge($acf_query, $wp_query->posts));` call.

I didn't want to call another `if get_field('featured_posts')` check after the WP_Query if I don't have too - All help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is the value of `array_unique($wp_query->posts)` the same as `$wp_query->posts`? If yes, then you could initialize the `$acf_query` as an empty array before the `if` and leave the rest of the code untouched. That way you will always do a merge with an empty array but there is no need for a second `if` statement.

Comment: @naszy, this is just the answer that I was looking for, thanks for explaining it! I was just overthinking it but this is the simplest and it's efficient.